# Trying to import classes from parent folder as a package

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

So, I'm trying to learn a little bit more of how the `__init__.py` file works. It supposedly give you the ability to import a dictionaries as a package. I use VS code. My `test1.py` run as expected, but the `test2.py` file dosen't. It gives me the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subdir'`. I run the scripts from `test1.py` and `test2.py`.

I've looked up many resources, but I haven't got it too work yet. In `test2.py`, I try to import the `Apple` class from `class1.py` and the `Banana` class from `class2.py` (both as a package). `test2.py` is trying to import from a parent directory which is probably what's causing the problem, but how can I make it work?

**directory structure**

```
init_file_testing/
                   test1.py
                   subdir/
                          __init__.py
                          class1.py
                          class2.py
                          subdir2/
                                  test2.py
```

**test1.py**

```
from subdir import Apple
from subdir import Banana

a = Apple("red")
print(a)

b = Banana("yellow")
print(b)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from subdir.test_class1 import Apple
from subdir.test_class2 import Banana
```

**class1.py**

```
class Apple:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"The color of the apple is {self.color}"
```

**class2.py**

```
class Banana:
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.color = color
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"The color of the banana is {self.color}"
```

**test2.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from subdir import Apple
from subdir import Banana

a = Apple("red")
print(a)

b = Banana("yellow")
print(b)
```

Comment: From where are you executing the scripts?

Comment: @alexpdev From test1.py and test2.py. It runs fine in test1.py, but not in test2.py. I've updated the file names in my post because I realize that the filenames was a little bit confusing.

Comment: After looking at your question closer, I don't really understand why you are trying to run `test2.py` ?  Is this an example of a real package you are trying to build? Typically all the entry points into a package are placed in the top level somewhere.

Comment: @alexpdev I'm just trying to learn more about the workings of the `__init__.py` file. So when I was able to get the class imports to work in the `test1.py` file (which is in a parent directory relative to the `__init__.py` file), I also wanted to see if I could get it to work in the `test2.py` file (which is in a child directory relative to the `__init__.py` file)

Comment: @alexpdev I see! Thank you for clarifying that. I appreciate it!

Comment: "From where are you executing the scripts" **does not** mean "which Python source file is the starting point of the program?" It means "when you start the program, what is the current working directory?".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel  Nobody said that is what it meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `python test1.py` and it works, that implies (unless you used some other technique to set up the `sys.path`) you are in the `init_file_testing` folder, and that folder is on the path that is searched for Python modules. If you want to `from subdir import` something, then you need that folder on your path - because that is the folder that contains the `subdir` package.

If you run `python test2.py` and *the file is found*, that implies (similar logic) you are in `subdir2`. Hacking the path with `sys.path.append("..")` **does not** help, because that puts the `subdir` folder on the path, but you need the `init_file_testing` folder instead. In relative terms, that is `sys.path.append("../..")`.

---

However, if you are willing to use relative paths as part of a hack to make this work, then *why not just [use relative imports](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+relative+imports) instead*? This is how you are intended to work within packages.

That looks like:

**`test1.py`**

```
from .subdir import Apple, Banana
```

**`__init__.py`**

```
from .class1 import Apple
from .class2 import Banana
```

**`test2.py`**

```
from ..subdir import Apple, Banana
```

Then, you only need to ensure that the package root (`init_file_testing`) is on the module search path, no matter which module you start from; and that you start from either the root folder or from *outside* the package folders (which you *should do anyway*). One easy way to ensure the path is set up is by *installing* your package in a virtual environment (which is the recommended approach for development anyway). You can also do it with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Thank you for a clarifying answer!